# Sliding between activities on Android

Tags: android, slideshow

So i have a general layout im using on multiple activities.

> Name
>
> Image
>
> Some description of image

Basically, i want to slide between the activities so they show the information after slides instead of clicking buttons to go to the activities.

Ive already looked at a viewpager but am unsure how to have unique images and unique text on each slide.

How do i do this without losing any of the layout and information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.02" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.28" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="\nDescription"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="0.50" />
</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: Is there a simpler tutorial showing what i need, sorry im a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many kind of controls can do, ViewPager, ViewFlipper, Gallery, ...
Your use case is not so clear, please take a look on these controls first, or describe the use case, then we choose the best view for you.

Comment: @Bimal Download source code for PVI and add it into your project http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the ViewPager I'm developing a sample project that show how to use the ViewPager. If you are interested you can take a look at https://github.com/filippofavaro/ViewPager-Demo